# How to pass parameters to msi through bundle

Tags: parameters, cmd, wix, bundle

All I need is to install the same modules during updating that were chosen by user for the first time. I was trying just to pass parameters for wix but failed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291103/to-start-process-passing-parameters-to-wix-installer.

I have added variable to bootstrapper for passing parameters from command line to msi. But it doesn't work properly.
Code, added to bundle:

```
 <Variable Name="INSTALL_SOFTWARE" bal:Overridable="yes"/>
 <MsiProperty Name="INSTALL_SOFTWARE" Value="[INSTALL_SOFTWARE]"/>
```

Property to change, 1 by default. I should also say that is can be set from ui(radiobuttons)

```
   <Property Id="INSTALL_SOFTWARE">1</Property>
```

I am using this command:

```
InstallerBundle.exe INSTALL_SOFTWARE=2
```

And nothing is choosen in GUI dialog:

```
   <Control Id="SoftwareChoseButton" Type="RadioButtonGroup" Width="55" Height="128" X="34" Y="71" Property="INSTALL_SOFTWARE">
                <RadioButtonGroup Property="INSTALL_SOFTWARE">
```

As I can understand, the parameter is not passed.... How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to specify the MsiProperty like this inside your bundle:

```
<MsiPackage Id='MyApp' Description='My Application' SourceFile="$(var.SetupMyApp.TargetPath)">
  <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[MyAppInstallLocation]"/>
</MsiPackage>
```

And then, assuming `myBootStrapper` is your `BootstrapperApplication` object:

```
myBootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["MyAppInstallLocation"] = "C:\MyApp";
```

somewhere in your custom bootstrapper code, obviously before you start the install.

Comment: I have VsiProperty in bundle. I don't know what magic but change to <Variable Name="install_software" Value="1" Type="string" bal:Overridable="yes"/> helped. Anyway, thank you for help.